# How would you avoid having to use User.find_by_id(id) || User.find_by_slug(id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

The idea behind Friendly_ID is that you can use a slug or id to retrieve a record.
So `User.friendly.find(id)` will retrieve a record using either the slug or id. If the record isn't found, it raises an error.
I want to find the record but return **nil** if the record is not found.
For now, the only way I know of is something like this:

```
u = User.find_by_id() || User.find_by_slug()
```

This won't search through old slugs plus it's clunky. Is there a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not optimal but you could try using raw sql in a where method call. Try:

```
u = User.where("id ='...' or slug ='...')
```

If you want to avoid raw sql you can use Arel:

```
users = Arel::Table.new(:users)
u = users.where(users[:id].eq(...).or(users[:slug].eq('...')))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `nil` as value when the record is not found, you may assign `nil` in the `rescue` block like below:

```
begin
  u = User.friendly.find(id)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  u = nil
end
```

As of [find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) documentation, it raises [ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.6/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound.html) if no record can be found.

But if you don't want to use exception handling, then you may have to use the clunky solution:

```
u = User.find_by "id = ? or slug = ?", <ID>, <SLUG>
```